# Linux Ubuntu Server x32 not recognizing my hard drive

Tags: linux, sata, ibm-server

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server x32 on my IBM eServer xSeries 365. The installer says it can not recognize my drive.

I have 2 hot-swap Maxtor ATLAS 10K V 73GB Ultra320 SCSI drives and both are visible to my BIOS.

What should I do?

Comment: Are the jumpers on the drives set correctly?  Can you try the drives one at a time and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: What do you mean? Also i forgot to mention They're Maxtor ATLAS 10K V 73 GB Ultra32 SCSI.

Comment: Jumpers are little pins that designate whether the hard drive is primary/secondary/master/slave.  Check [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6687431_install-ultra320-scsi-hard-drive.html) for how to do that.  Also, are the drives formatted?  See [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1793713) for a thread that has some resemblance to your situation.  Lastly, [one other thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1704977) was resolved by configuring the raid card correctly.

Comment: Ok i think it probably needs configuring. And thank you very much :)

Comment: If both drives are visible to the hostadapter then they are already jumpered to different SCSI IDs.  (BTW. Why a SATA tag and Ultra320 SCSI drives? )